# Convert matlab date in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, matlab

I have a set of matlab formatted timestamps I need to convert to Python datetime in a pandas dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[737098.4, 737098.5, 737098.6, 737098.7], columns=['matlab_datenum'])
df
       matlab_datenum
0        737098.4
1        737098.5
2        737098.6
3        737098.7
```

I came across the following code to convert matlab dateformat to python format, but am uncertain how to implement in a dataframe

```
python_datetime = datetime.fromordinal(int(matlab_datenum)) + timedelta(days=matlab_datenum%1) - timedelta(days = 366)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the world of `apply` functions -

```
df['python_datetime'] = df['matlab_datenum'].apply(lambda matlab_datenum: datetime.fromordinal(int(matlab_datenum)) + timedelta(days=matlab_datenum%1))
```

So for each of the `matlab_datenum` present in your dataframe, `apply` function will actually iterate over each of them and execute the anonymous function `lambda` - which has been defined to convert each corresponding `matlab_datenum` to a python datetime.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 5):

A much faster solution is to use pandas `to_datetime` function directly. The advantage of this method is that it can be used also to achieve a resolution beyond days (I used seconds in the code below).

```
import pandas as pd
#719529 is the number of days from matlab epoch to Unix epoch
pd.to_datetime(matlab_datenum-719529,unit='d').round('s')
```

A simple example:

```
matlab_datenum=np.array([737694.83333333, 737694.84027778, 737694.84722222])

In [107]: pd.to_datetime(matlab_datenum-719529,unit='d').round('s')
Out[107]: DatetimeIndex(['2019-09-26 20:00:00', '2019-09-26 20:10:00','2019-09-26 20:20:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answer has one problem, and you should account for the time shift; use:

```
.apply(lambda matlab_datenum: date.fromordinal(int(matlab_datenum)) + timedelta(days=matlab_datenum%1) - timedelta(days = 366))
```